# Avoid redundancy in RPM spec file

Tags: rpm-spec

I try to build a simple `noarch` package. I build the package with:

```
rpmbuild -bb --build-in-place --define "_topdir $(pwd)/rpm" typeset-pdf.spec
```

This is the specification:

```
Name:       typeset-pdf
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Typeset PDF
License:    Proprietary
BuildArch:  noarch

%description
Use TeX templates to typeset PDF files.

%prep

%build

%install
install -D -t %{buildroot}/%{_bindir} %{name}
install -D -t %{buildroot}/%{_datadir}/%{name}/lieferschein \
        lieferschein/lieferschein.tex.tt \
        lieferschein/logo.eps

%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}
%{_datadir}/%{name}/lieferschein/lieferschein.tex.tt
%{_datadir}/%{name}/lieferschein/logo.eps

%changelog
```

The contents of the `%install` and `%files` sections is almost identical. Is it possible to avoid this redundancy? Can I use the contents of the `%files` section anyhow in the `%install` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to avoid this redundancy

Yes, doing something like (very approximate code!):

```
%install
<your install commands>
find %{buildroot} > installed-files

%files -f installed-files
```

But this is delicate and you will run into trouble packaging `/usr/bin/` and other system directories.

## Why not?

I would recommend you not avoiding these duplicates. This is how `rpm` works and it has its value (especially when creating multiple packages with the same spec file). Note that in the `%install` section you need to create `/usr/bin/` etc, while you should **not** package them under `%files`.

Note also that under `%files` you can specify a directory which will package the directory recursively:

```
%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}
%{_datadir}/%{name}
```

would suffice in your case.

Again: make sure to package **all** files and directories that belong to your package, but nothing more. Every file and directory can only belong to one `rpm` package. Forgetting to package your top directory for example will leave it lying around when you uninstall your `rpm`.

Comment: I tried to implement the solution, I should not. I am still not convinced, why not. I tried to avoid the problems, you have mentioned. Can you take a look and explain, in which cases it will still fail?

Answer (score 0):

The option [Cris Maes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018839/402322) voted against:

```
Name:       typeset-pdf
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Typeset PDF
License:    Proprietary
BuildArch:  noarch

%description
Use TeX templates to typeset PDF files.

%prep

%build

%install
> FILES
file ()
{
  install -m 0644 -D -t "%{buildroot}/$(dirname "$1/$2")" "$2"
  echo "$1/$2" >> FILES
}
dir ()
{
  mkdir -p -m 0755 "%{buildroot}/$1/$2"
  echo "%dir $1/$2" >> FILES
}
file %{_bindir}              typeset-pdf
dir  %{_datadir}             typeset-pdf
dir  %{_datadir}/typeset-pdf lieferschein
file %{_datadir}/typeset-pdf lieferschein/lieferschein.tex.tt
file %{_datadir}/typeset-pdf lieferschein/logo.eps

%files -f FILES

%changelog
```

Comment: Did you try installing this? I think you'll have trouble because your are probably packaging directories you shouldn't. Your code is dependent on the number of subdirectories your are packaging.
It might work, and you might be happy with it, but for me this is more complicated than the solution I proposed. Just try it out :)

Comment: @ChrisMaes You are right. It did not clean up the directories.

Comment: Note that you can use `rpm -qlp <path-to-rpm-package>` to query the files and directories packaged inside an rpm. This can speed up the debugging :)

Comment: It is necessary to distinguish between files and directories. I changed that.

Comment: You will get to something that is working in the end, but I stand my case that my proposal was much simpler in code and simpler to maintain.